# Is it possible to have an Ingress point to a Service from another namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

What I want to do is have a service in the `default` namespace and ingresses in my other namespaces, which point to that service. I tried implementing the service and Ingress shown below, but it didn't work.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: serviceX
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: serviceX.default.svc.cluster.local
ports:
- port: 123


kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: web-ingress-test-vpndev
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - abc.my-namespace.domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret-my-namespace
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceX
          servicePort: 123
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress: {}
```

I know that I could implement the service in every namespace, but I was wondering if it's possible to have a single service. If I try to type the `externalName` of the service in the `backend->serviceName` handler of the ingress, I get and error saying that the name of the service can only contain numbers, letter and '-'.

Comment: while providing `serviceName` in the ingress manifest can you try giving FQDN, that would be `serviceX.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @viveksinghggits If i try to configure the serviceName like this `serviceName: serviceX.default.svc.cluster.local` I get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have to say that this isnt a good way. as all of ingress in different NS would be convert to Nginx Rule and take effect in ingress-controller pod.

And if you take a look the Nginx Rule(`nginx.conf` in ingress-controller pod), you will see each block of `location` in `nginx.conf` has variable `set $namespace      "****";` which means the ingress has been isolated by NS

Also, if you still want to implement your idea, might need to modify the ingress-contoller.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible and also don't think it's a good idea. Ingress is not a cluster level resource. Each namespace should have its own instance.

Answer (score 3):

I achieve this using Istio. It's not the main reason why we are using it, but the traffic management features allows this kind of thing.

```
+--Namespace A-------------------------------+
|                                            |
|  +-------+   +-------+   +--------------+  |
|  |Ingress+--->Service+--->VirtualService|  |
|  +-------+   +-------+   +------+-------+  |
|                                 |          |
+--------------------------------------------+
                                  |
                  +---------------+
                  |
                  |      +--Namespace B---------+
                  |      |                      |
                  |      |  +-------+    +---+  |
                  +--------->Service+---->Pod|  |
                         |  +-------+    +---+  |
                         |                      |
                         +----------------------+
```

With Istio you can have your ingress in one namespace, a service without Selector (because there is no pod here) and a virtual service that route the traffic on service.namespaceA to service.namespaceB.

I'am using this to achieve blue-green deployment. Imagine the same principle than above but with 3 namespaces :

- Namespace-A (with ingress, service and virtualService)
- Namespace-B-blue (with blue services and pods)
- Namespace-B-green (with green services and pods)

The switch between blue and green version is managed by the virtualService in the namespace-A. The advantage is that you can test the green version (smoke test) using routing features of istio before release it to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to post this here to help others in future. This works on AWS but it may not on other cloud infra. If you want a single ALB to connect to services in different namespace to itself, you create two k8s ingress, but group them together.

Namespace A

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
  namespace: A
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name": "group"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order": "1"
  namespace: A
spec:
  rules:
  - host: latest.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-1
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

Namespace B

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-2
  namespace: B
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name": "group"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order": "2"
  namespace: B
spec:
  rules:
  - host: other.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-2
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

I've removed many annotations for brevity, but this will create a single ALB, with two ingress resources that enable the same domain to point into different services across different namespaces.